# Bootstrap tags input not working with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap tags input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) to make tags inside text input,in the documentation:

> Just add data-role="tagsinput" to your input field to automatically
>   change it to a tags input field.

But when using **jquery before function**:

```
$('#addrun').click(function () {
            $('#addrun').before('<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing" data-role="tagsinput" />');    
        });
```

it is displayed like any text input with text inside and no tags.

any help ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bootstrap is run at page load as an self-executing function. By adding a new element to the DOM - By that time, `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` wouldn't know anything about it. So you'll have to Initialise it after adding it to the DOM document via JavaScript.

To refresh input tags ([Bootstrap Tagsinput Docs](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#methods)):

```
$('input').tagsinput('refresh');
```

So for you, you'd need to:

```
/** 
 * On <div id="addrun"> on click,
 * pre-apend it with an new Input
 *
 * Then refresh Bootstrap. 
**/
$('#addrun').click(function(){

     $('#addrun').before(
         '<input type="text" '+
         'value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing" '+
         'data-role="tagsinput" />'
     ); 

     //Now run bootstrap.js to re-search
     //new data-* elements
     $('input').tagsinput('refresh');   
});
```

Hope that helps! Although, the above `$('input')` will refresh every `<input>` tag in the whole document, so you could instead give the prepended `<input>` tag an .class or an #ID for quicker access =)

### Update:

As **koala_dev** did correctly mention within the comments, you probably wouldn't need to initialise it via `$('selector').tagsinput('refresh')` but rather just:

```
     $('#selecor').tagsinput();
```

`.tagsinput('refresh')` would normally be actioned on an `.tagsinput()` input that's already initialised with new options given.

Comment: No problem! If there's anything else, let me know =)!

Comment: Your explanation is kind of misleading, this is not an official Bootstrap plugin so `bootstrap.js` is not really a part of the issue, also your're not "re-initializing" but rather initializing the plugin in the new element, also I'm not sure you need to call the refresh method, I believe calling `tagsinput()` would suffice

Comment: And you don't need a class or ID to apply the plugin to the new element, you can do `var $newInput = $('<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing" data-role="tagsinput" />'); $('#addrun').before($newInput); $newInput.tagsinput();`

Comment: actually it is working but after refresh the new input is read only !! any suggestions ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/khYh8/17/ Change it to target an ID of the input and indeed adjust it to `.tagsinput();` (but I wasn't able to replicate the issue)

Comment: please check this question and I am sure you will be able to help me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275570/twitter-bootstrap-input-tags-not-working-with-jquery-before

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this could definitely be worth mentioning in the docs: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 8):

I made it working following ways. It was showing problem $(..).tagsinput() was not found and I could now update the tags with new values.

I removed first and last line from file bootstrap-tagsinput.js, that is `'(function ($) {'` and `'})(window.jQuery)'`.

And called the below two lines where tags was required to display and update.

```
$("input[data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput('removeAll');
$("input[data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput('add', 'New Value');
```

Comment: After searching for so long, this solution finally worked for me!