# Twitter bootstrap input tags not working with Jquery before()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Jquery to clone() a div and change its children's id, one of the children is a [Bootstrap-tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

You can find a [Demo here](https://googledrive.com/host/0B-IBanqetxwNSlpQY1E5WC01Rzg/index.html).

After clicking **add new run** a new div is added but the tags input is uneditable!!

here is my code (and you can view the full code [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-IBanqetxwNaC1Jc3V5bEhaamM/edit?usp=drive_web)
):

```
$('#addrun').click(function () {

                var s = $('#run1')
                    .clone()
                    .attr('id', '#run' + (++runNum))
                    .wrap('<div>');



                s.find('#tag1').attr('id', 'tag2');
                $('#tag2').tagsinput();
                $('#addrun').before(s.parent().html());

                $(".well").on('click', '.expandbtn', function () {
                    var $this = $(this).parent();
                    var $collapse = $this.closest('.RunWell').find('.SystemFiles');
                    $collapse.collapse('toggle');
                });
                $('.SystemFiles').collapse('collapse');

            });
```

Comment: You can't just clone radio inputs like that.  Every radio with the same name is counted as being a part of the same control.

Comment: It's uneditable because JavaScript is running into an error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'collapse'`

Comment: I removed the radio buttons and the collapse functions, and still uneditable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `.tagsinput()` on `#tag2` after adding it to the page.

```
$('#addrun').before(s.parent().html());
$('#tag2').tagsinput();
```

**Edit:**

This is probably due to how the TagsInput plugin initializes itself. What I would do is create a template of your empty run container and hide it on the page or load it via JavaScript.

```
<div class="control-group hide" id="ControlGroupTemplate">
  <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Tools :</label>
  <input type="text" class="tags" id="tag1" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing"
    data-role="tagsinput" />
  <br />
  <div class="SystemFiles" data-role="collapsible">
    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">OP Customer DLIS files (PUC)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">OP logup DLIS files (LUP)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="file1" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">OP Producer DLIS files (PUP)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="file2" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">OP well folder</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="file3" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">Prints</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="file4" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-mini link-btn expandbtn" id="exp" type="button">expand toggle</button>
  <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down">
  </span>Duplicate</button>
</div>
```

Then you clone the `ControlGroupTemplate` and apply the `TagsInput` method to it.

```
var s = $('#ControlGroupTemplate')
  .clone()
  .attr('id', '#run' + (++runNum))
  .wrap('<div>');

s.find('#tag1').attr('id', 'tag2');
$('#addrun').before(s.parent().html());
$('#tag2').tagsinput();
```

I would even use this method to add your initial run to the page in your `document.ready()` handler.

Comment: I did , and nothing has changed.

Comment: actually it added a new one that is working !!! but another one that is not working WTH !!
you can check it from here
https://googledrive.com/host/0B-IBanqetxwNSlpQY1E5WC01Rzg/index2.html