# Value of form input not changing on readyState using Bootstrap Tags Input and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="./results.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default btn-responsive" role="button">
    <input name="q" id="query" value="" data-role="tagsinput"/>
</form>
```

After loading the page using AJAX, I want to populate the value field with the `http.responseText`. I'm trying doing it this way:

```
function AjaxFunction()
{
    url = 'fbserver.php';
    http.open("GET",url, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (http.readyState == 4)
        {
            $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
            var query = http.responseText; // The user's interests as a string
            document.getElementById("query").value = query;
            /* Tried refreshing the input here like suggested in the linked question ($('input').tagsinput();) */
        }
    }
    http.send(null);
}
```

However, it's not working, leaving the form input empty and the value attribute unchanged. I tried `document.getElementById("query").name = query;` and the `name` attribute changes normally.

I guess it has something to do with the tagsinput plugin as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211973/bootstrap-tags-input-not-working-with-jquery), but I was unable to fix this problem based on the answers. Any help would be appreciated! ;)

Comment: Please test this: document.getElementById("query").attributes["name"]= "query";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the api of the plugin rather putting the text values directly.

I am using jQuery (and I think the plugin also has a dependency on it, so you can use this approach also). So inyour ajax call, you can:

```
$('#query').tagsinput('add', http.responseText);
```

You can view the other methods here: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: I'm a jQuery newbie, so sorry for the simplistic questions, but should this line be placed in the AjaxFunction instead of document.getElementById("query").value = query; (of course in a for loop traversing the response's words)? Cause I can't make it work...

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted my code. Yes, you are correct, this should be placed on your AjaxFunction and replace the line as you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! :) It works like a charm! Just remove the semicolon after http.responseText (just a typo). ;)